# How to dump sql file from local to server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL file in my local computer size of 9.5Gb. And I want the dump that SQL into the live server through the command line. I want to know the command line to dup the SQL from local to live server

Comment: Is the SQL file a backup of an existing database?

Comment: you need to have some kind of service running on the live server, like FTP Service for you to move files

Comment: I was assuming you wanted to actually run the SQL on the target server, but maybe I was wrong, after reading @SudiptaMondal's comment. But here's an example command in case useful: mysql -hmyserver -umyuser -pmypwd -Dmydatabase <c:\mypath\mysql.sql

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < /path of sql file
```

Comment: are you sure, running this would help the OP in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u username -p db_name -h hostname < /path/file.sql